# Set products in Python

Tags: python, math

A product of n copies of a set S is denoted S<sup>n</sup>. For example, {0, 1}<sup>3</sup> is the set of all 3­-bit sequences:

{0,1}<sup>3</sup> = {(0,0,0),(0,0,1),(0,1,0),(0,1,1),(1,0,0),(1,0,1),(1,1,0),(1,1,1)}

What's the simplest way to replicate this idea in Python?

Comment: is it just {0,1} or could it be anything?

Comment: Arbitrary sets would be nice, as well as an arbitrary n.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In Python 2.6 or newer you can use [itertools.product](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) with the optional argument `repeat`:

```
>>> from itertools import product
>>> s1 = set((0, 1))
>>> set(product(s1, repeat = 3))
```

For older versions of Python you can implement `product` using the code found in the documentation:

```
def product(*args, **kwds):
    # product('ABCD', 'xy') --> Ax Ay Bx By Cx Cy Dx Dy
    # product(range(2), repeat=3) --> 000 001 010 011 100 101 110 111
    pools = map(tuple, args) * kwds.get('repeat', 1)
    result = [[]]
    for pool in pools:
        result = [x+[y] for x in result for y in pool]
    for prod in result:
        yield tuple(prod)
```

Answer (score 3):

I suppose this works?

```
>>> s1 = set((0,1))
>>> set(itertools.product(s1,s1,s1))
set([(0, 1, 1), (1, 1, 0), (1, 0, 0), (0, 0, 1), (1, 0, 1), (0, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0), (1, 1, 1)])
```

Answer (score 1):

Mark, good idea.

```
>>> def set_product(the_set, n):
    return set(itertools.product(the_set, repeat=n))

>>> s2 = set((0,1,2))
>>> set_product(s2, 3)
set([(0, 1, 1), (0, 1, 2), (1, 0, 1), (0, 2, 1), (2, 2, 0), (0, 2, 0), (0, 2, 2), (1, 0, 0), (2, 0, 1), (1, 2, 0), (2, 0, 0), (1, 2, 1), (0, 0, 2), (2, 2, 2), (1, 2, 2), (2, 0, 2), (0, 0, 1), (0, 0, 0), (2, 1, 2), (1, 1, 1), (0, 1, 0), (1, 1, 0), (2, 1, 0), (2, 2, 1), (2, 1, 1), (1, 1, 2), (1, 0, 2)])
```

You could also extend the set type and make the `__pow__` method do this.

Answer (score 0):

```
print 'You can do like this with generator:'
print set((a,b,c) for a in s1 for b in s1 for c in s1)
```